# Proper way to execute a large SQL query in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query that I used my vb.net application to run it, but i have a problem when It exceeds to its command timeout property. I set it to 300, any tips or suggestions?

here is the snippet of my code in vb.net

```
  .ExecuteQuery("exec spCentrIX_PracticeSet '" & oCompany & "','" & .SecDatabaseName & "'", sDataSet)
  Application.DoEvents()
  .ExecuteQuery("exec spCentrIX_PracticeSet '" & oCompany & "','" & .SetDatabaseName & "'", sDataSet)
  Application.DoEvents()
  .ExecuteQuery("exec spCentrIX_PracticeSet '" & oCompany & "','" & .TranDatabaseName & "'", sDataSet)
  Application.DoEvents()
```

same script that run three times. this script gets all the data from the 3 databases which runs okie. however, when it is running...it exceeds the connection timeout of my code.

Comment: What problem do you have, can you show your code?

Comment: Maybe if you post your SQL, or some details about the structure of the info you're trying to retrieve we can help you optimize it.  Maybe the query can be optimized, maybe you need to use a paging strategy, etc.  But without more info we can't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the timeout to zero will never time out, this is not advised in a production environment but if you really really want to wait till it is finished it will do the trick. You would want to investigate ways to optimise the query if possible. Also run it asynchronously, maybe using backgroundworker.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20627/BackgroundWorker-Threads-and-Supporting-Cancel

Comment: a backgroundworker...sounds new to me...can you provide me some examples?

Comment: I added a link from a quick google search, I have not actually used it but Code Project is a good site. Be careful posting on SO before doing some investigation yourself, people tend to discourage that.

Comment: I am wondering if Tasks would be a better/simpler solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.100%29.aspx . Also, @dave, do you need `.ExecuteQeury` or `.ExecuteNonQuery`? (You may have shortened your code such that I can't tell.)